# How do we call when one model is trained by another?

Tags: terminology, transfer-learning

Suppose I have one model (say, for image classification) as black box. I don't posess it and don't know it's parameters. Suppose it is web API.

Then I take bunch of images, classify them by this model and pass them as training set to my own model.

So, the knowledge of first model is transmitted to second one.

What is the term for this?

[Transfer learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_learning) looks is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any term for this other than trying to create artificial training dataset. Just a warning though, if you use another models output (instead of true label) you are likely to amplify the error from previous model, no matter how good your model is. (feeding picture of a dog when it's actually a cat).

Transfer learning is actually quite different. In transfer learning, part of the pre-trained model (e.g., VGG_19) is retained/frozen and custom layers are added to fit specific objective.

The retained layers basically are tuned to detect different data structures on a larger/diverse data while the specific neural network layers are to create final layer of abstraction for the specific task.

More technical and intuitive article - https://blog.slavv.com/a-gentle-intro-to-transfer-learning-2c0b674375a0